# How to add a element into array object?

Tags: php, html, arrays

if i have an json array like this:

```
{
 "code": 1,
 "data_question": [
 {
   "id_question": "9",
   "id_user": "9",
   "name": "name"
 }
],
"last_page": 1,
"count_data": 8
}
```

And my question is how to add an element into data_question object to be like this:

```
{
 "code": 1,
 "data_question": [
 {
   "id_question": "9",
   "id_user": "9",
   "name": "name"
   "age":"12" <--------
 }
],
"last_page": 1,
"count_data": 8
}
```

Please have a look this screeshot:
[Image PHP Code](https://image.ibb.co/bGhUun/1.png)
[Image JSON](https://image.ibb.co/nGpyn7/1.png)

Thank for your help :)

Comment: `$array["data_question"][0]["age"] = 12` ?

Comment: @apokryfos It will make a new object in "data_question"

Comment: You decoded it right `json_decode($JSON, true)`?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix yes

Comment: Sorry, your code showed only pulling some data from the DB, and no decoding.  If you store this JSON in the DB, that has many shortcomings that will probably cause you issues later.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix hm, so i cant manual add other element?

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $sql_total_answer = "SELECT * FROM tbl_answer WHERE id_question=$row[id_question]";
  $count_total_answer = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $sql_total_answer));

  $array[] = $row;
 }`

Comment: I didn't say that, I said it has shortcomings.  Such as how would you look up the record by question id 9 with an age of 12 with the present setup.  What query would you use to find records with that?  How do you control that they answer a question of a give id only 1 time? etc...  This may or may not be an issue depending on your use case.

Comment: If I am to take your data literally then http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e849832c12921fb928ff69a0db8969e541d9b924 is what happens

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix actually i have a tbl_question and tbl_answer, and i want to count the how many answer for 1 primary key in tbl_question

Comment: @ASHafizullah - good luck.

Comment: @apokryfos please check this image https://ibb.co/nBZL0S and https://ibb.co/dGgYLS

Comment: Well that's what happens when the data you share is different to the data you actually have

Comment: From the screenshot of your code, it looks like you want `$row["count_answer"] = $count_total_answer;` before `$array[] = $row;`

Comment: @salathe It will be like this https://image.ibb.co/cikDn7/1.png

Comment: @ASHafizullah No, it won't.

Comment: @salathe Nice... thanks for your help :))

Comment: Just to be clear, I meant like in this example: https://eval.in/private/1ec8183b56909a

Comment: @salathe yes, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
<?php 
$txt = '{
 "code": 1,
 "data_question": [
 {
   "id_question": "9",
   "id_user": "9",
   "name": "name"
 }
],
"last_page": 1,
"count_data": 8
}';

$data = json_decode($txt,true);
$data['data_question'][0]['age'] = 12; 
echo json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thanks but please look this screenshot ibb.co/nBZL0S and ibb.co/dGgYLS

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
$array["data_question"][0]["age"] = "12";     
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Thanks but please look this screenshot ibb.co/nBZL0S and ibb.co/dGgYLS

Comment: Please edit:
$array[] = $row;
$array[$i]["count_answer"] = $count_total_answer;//$i = 0  when init
$i++;